# How to animate transform: rotate(Xdeg);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to animate `transform: rotate(Xdeg);` ?

e.g. I have a`div` with id "awesomeDiv" and try to animate the rotation on hover.

It should animate from `-24deg` to `0deg` on hover and back from `0deg`to `-24deg` again if the mouse goes out.

I've tried it like this:

```js
$("#awesomeDiv").hover(
   function()
   {
      $(this).animate({
        transform : "rotate(0deg)"
      });
   },
   function()
   {
      $(this).animate({
        transform: "rotate(-24deg)"
      });
   }
);
```

```css
div#awesomeDiv {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #D8D8D8;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   transform: rotate(-24deg);
  
   margin-left:30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   background-image: url("http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.218467778.5415/fc,220x200,white.u2.jpg");
}

div#centerMe {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 92px;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="awesomeDiv">
  <div id="centerMe">
     <center>Im Aw<span style="color:black">es</span>ome!</center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know you've specifically mentioned jQuery but why not do this with pure CSS transitions?

Comment: I am open for any solution.

Comment: Ok, so you want to rotate from -24deg to 0deg on hover in and then reverse on hover out?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thats what I try to achieve.

Comment: Hmm, I am confused by the edit to the question because both say from -24deg to 0deg (mouse in and out). Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry Harry, it was a mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the animate property of `step`, like so.

```
var awesomeDiv = $('#awesomeDiv');

$({rotation: 0}).animate({rotation: 360}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function () {
        awesomeDiv.css({transform: 'rotate(' + this.rotation + 'deg)'});
        console.log(this.rotation);
    }
});
```

[Demo in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kekavubaqa/edit?js,output)

For something this simple, I would go with using CSS transitions or animations.

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with simple CSS transitions itself like in the below snippet. Just set the `transition` property on the `div#awesomeDiv` and then add the `transform: rotate(0deg)` to the `:hover` state.

In the `transition` property, you can also specify the duration over which the movement should take place, the timing function (like ease, ease-in, ease-out etc) and any delays.

```css
div#awesomeDiv {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #D8D8D8;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   transform: rotate(-24deg);
  
   margin-left:30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   background-image: url("http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.218467778.5415/fc,220x200,white.u2.jpg");
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

div#centerMe {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 92px;
   color: white;
}
div#awesomeDiv:hover{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="awesomeDiv">
  <div id="centerMe">
     <center>Im Awesome!</center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Javascript and jQuery only to modify the CSS, since CSS can perform this task easily (and it make it reusable, and let your jQuery cleaner). Here is an example of code :

```js
/* jQuery 1.9.1 */
$(function() {
    $('#awesomeDiv').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('awesomeDiv-rotated');
  });

  $('#awesomeDiv').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('awesomeDiv-rotated');
  });
});
```

```css
.awesomeDiv {
  height : 100px;
  width : 100px;
  background-color : lightgrey;
  transition : all .25s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.awesomeDiv-rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
          transform: rotate(-24deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="awesomeDiv" class="awesomeDiv">
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2bks6yw0/)

**Edit**

You might want to only use CSS to perform such a simple task as this one. It is possible, here is how you might do this (CSS only) :

```css
#awesomeDiv {
  height : 100px;
  width : 100px;
  background-color : lightgrey;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition : all .25s ease-in-out;
}

#awesomeDiv:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
          transform: rotate(-24deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="awesomeDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here it is with CSS transition and transform (you said in your comment that you are open to any solution, so going the more natural way)

```css
#awesomeDiv {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#awesomeDiv:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

div#awesomeDiv {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #D8D8D8;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   transform: rotate(-24deg);
  
   margin-left:30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   background-image: url("http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.218467778.5415/fc,220x200,white.u2.jpg");
}

div#centerMe {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 92px;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="awesomeDiv">
  <div id="centerMe">
     <center>Im Aw<span style="color:black">es</span>ome!</center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) work only for numeric values.

> The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property. The only required parameter is a plain object of CSS properties. This object is similar to the one that can be sent to the .css() method, except that the range of properties is more restrictive.
>   All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality .

so just use jquery's css() to use transform instead of animate.

```js
$("#awesomeDiv").hover(
   function()
   {
      $(this).css({
        transform : "rotate(0deg)"
      });
   },
   function()
   {
      $(this).css({
        transform: "rotate(-24deg)"
      });
   }
);
```

```css
div#awesomeDiv {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #D8D8D8;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   transform: rotate(-24deg);
  
   margin-left:30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   background-image: url("http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.218467778.5415/fc,220x200,white.u2.jpg");
}

div#centerMe {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 92px;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="awesomeDiv">
  <div id="centerMe">
     <center>Im Awesome!</center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple way is use CSS like this:

```
div#awesomeDiv {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #D8D8D8;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   transform: rotate(-24deg);
   transition: transform 1s;


   margin-left:30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   background-image: url("http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.218467778.5415/fc,220x200,white.u2.jpg");
}

div#awesomeDiv:hover {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

div#centerMe {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 92px;
   color: white;
}
```